# how to avoid checking thread interrupted everywhere in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have two algorithm A, B for computing solution for a NP hard problem, which may take a lot of time. Then in main thread M I create threadA and threadB for algorithm A and algorithm B respectively. When any of threadA or threadB finishing computing or both reach a timeout, M calls interrupt on those unfinished threads.
M repeat this procedure for more than 5,000 of test cases.

Since algorithm A and B does not have any interruptible operations, the interrupt will not cause interrupt exception, thus these unfinished threads will continue running in background, which finally exhausting heap memory because more and more unfinished threads.

Then I need to manually check thread's `isInterrupted` in both algorithm. But I do not want to check them everywhere for efficiency and code readability concern.

For example, the original algorithm is

```
public class AlgA {
  public void run() {
    do1();
    do2();
    ...
    do100();
  }
}
```

And I do not want

```
public class AlgA {
  public void run() throws InterruptedException {
    do1();
    check();
    do2();
    check();
    ...
    check();
    do100();
  }
  private void check() throws InterruptedException {
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
      throw new InterruptedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just call `Thread.sleep(0)` occasionally. This will force you to catch `InterruptedException`, and you can do whatever you need to do in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be wrapping the interrupt checking and method invocation in some util mehtod:

```
public class AlgA {
  protected static void checkAndCall(Runnable action) 
      throws InterrruptedException {
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
      throw new InterruptedException();
    }
    action.run()
  }

  public void run() {
    checkAndCall(this::do1);
    checkAndCall(this::do2);
    ...
    checkAndCall(this::do100);
  }
}
```